# How to set time for an RTC 5 Click in MPLAB X?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, rtc, mplabx

I am currently working as a design engineer intern. I am using an RTC 5 Click as part of my design to provide real solar time. It is nice that MPLAB X is able to generate sample code, but I have no idea how to set the time. This screenshot below is how the sample code sets the time. I can see that the setTime variable is set to 1503870020, but what year, month, day, hour, minute, and second does that translate into?

[image: The code snippet that shows one application]

The application calls the following function below.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code not as an image.Use the code Tag {}

Answer (score 1):

Usually in RTC, the time is counted from the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) that is  1 January 1970.

Here is a handy [converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

1503870020 gives you Sunday, August 27, 2017 9:40:20 PM GMT.

A majority of systems relies on that for time tracking.

Comment: @Tony you welcome. If this answer helped you, you can mark it as answered.